# Heavy linux server load when many files in directory

Tags: linux, filesystems

I have a website that generate images for each user, which are stored in `/images/user/`. I have a server with 8 CPUs, so maximum server load should be 8, but the load on my server reach 100, 150, 200. Average image size is 50 KB, average number of images created in 1 day is more than 50,000. The only way to decrease load is empty the images directory.

Is there any way to reduce the load to normal range?

Note : I thought to grouping generated images in more than 1 folders depend on date + time, such as:

1. images/user/18/11/15/10
2. images/user/18/11/15/11
3. images/user/19/11/15/1

Is that will make a difference?

Comment: There is insufficient information here.  I don't know why you think breaking things up into sub folders should make a difference, but if it is easy for you to test go ahead.  Is your problem I/O?  You need to find the root source of your problem.  What specific task or thing is causing the load?  How long does it take to generate 1 image?  How long does it take to generate 8 images in parallel?  Once you figure out how long it takes for a small set of images, math it out and figure out how long it should take for a typical days worth of images.

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/a/736876/126632

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - Is there any way to reduce the load to normal range?

Use [scientific method](https://serverfault.com/questions/646852/excessive-number-of-sleeping-processes-in-centos-howto-diagnose/646876#646876) to analyse the problem this really is science not guesswork.

- Use the usual tools, sar, free, top, iostat vmstat etc to gather information about your system.
- Make an informed decision about what changes to make.
- Monitor your system to see if the changes helped. If the didn't reanalize, rinse and repeat.

Comment: It seems your link is broken...