# Can really big folder (more than one million files) slow Nginx down?

Tags: nginx, filesystems

I mean, if I have the following folder structure:
`www/lang/comp/` - more than a million files here. Will the worker slowed down by looking for a file?
For example, `https://example.com/lang/comp/comp-3453459.html`

Is it will be better to divide such a folder into several smaller folders?

Comment: Nginx doesn't look for files, it just asks the OS to open a file. It depends how efficiently the OS handles very large directories.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the big folder can slow everything down.

It would depend on your filesystem, and there's a lot of good pointers and some advice here: [Filesystem large number of files in a single directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/43133/filesystem-large-number-of-files-in-a-single-directory)